# Why can't I create menu separators?

Tags: 11.04, menu

For some reason, I am unable to add separators to the menu in Ubuntu Classic. Is this feature broken, or is there something wrong?
[image]

Comment: I second you. I have the same issue. Please someone help us resolve this. This is a fresh installation of Ubuntu and I'm 100% sure I didn't temper it to cause this problem.

Comment: It seems to happen with any fresh install. I assume it's due to the phasing out of Gnome 2.

Answer (score 4):

I did it manually for now by editing `.config/menus/applications.menu`, adding
  `<Separator/>` inside `<Layout>...</Layout>` near the bottom of that file:

```
<Layout>
    <Merge type="menus"/>
    <Filename>Terminal.desktop</Filename>
    <Filename>gedit-1.desktop</Filename>
    <Filename>Firefox Web Browser.desktop</Filename>
    <Filename>Tomboy Notes.desktop</Filename>
    <Filename>Geeqie.desktop</Filename>
    <Filename>alacarte-made.desktop</Filename>
    <Menuname>alacarte-made</Menuname>
    <Separator/>
    <Menuname>Accessories</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Debian</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Education</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Games</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Graphics</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Internet</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Office</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Other</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Development</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Science</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Multimedia</Menuname>
    <Menuname>System</Menuname>
    <Menuname>Universal Access</Menuname>
    <Separator/>
    <Filename>ubuntu-software-center.desktop</Filename>
    <Merge type="files"/>
</Layout>
```

If you use the filemanager to get to `.config` (e.g. via `Places/Home Folder`)
 be sure to `Show Hidden Files` via `View/Show Hidden Files` or hit `Ctrl+H`.